# np.choose not giving desired result after broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I would like to pick the nth elements as specified in maxsuit from suitCounts. I did broadcast the maxsuit array so I do get a result, but not the desired one. Any suggestions what I'm doing conceptually wrong is appreciated. I don't understand the result of `np.choose(self.maxsuit[:,:,None]-1, self.suitCounts)`, which is not what I'm looking for.

```
>>> self.maxsuit
Out[38]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int64)

>>> self.maxsuit[:,:,None]-1
Out[33]: 
array([[[2],
        [2]],

       [[0],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [0]]], dtype=int64)
>>> self.suitCounts
Out[34]: 
array([[[2, 1, 3, 0],
        [1, 0, 3, 0]],

       [[4, 1, 2, 0],
        [3, 0, 3, 0]],

       [[2, 2, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0]]])
>>> np.choose(self.maxsuit[:,:,None]-1, self.suitCounts)
Out[35]: 
array([[[2, 2, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0]],

       [[2, 1, 3, 0],
        [1, 0, 3, 0]],

       [[2, 1, 3, 0],
        [1, 0, 3, 0]]])
```

The desired result would be:

```
[[3,3],[4,3],[2,1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`advanced-indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) for a broadcasted way to index into the array, like so -

```
In [415]: val     # Data array
Out[415]: 
array([[[2, 1, 3, 0],
        [1, 0, 3, 0]],

       [[4, 1, 2, 0],
        [3, 0, 3, 0]],

       [[2, 2, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0]]])

In [416]: idx     # Indexing array
Out[416]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])

In [417]: m,n = val.shape[:2]

In [418]: val[np.arange(m)[:,None],np.arange(n),idx-1]
Out[418]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

A bit cleaner way with [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) to use open range arrays -

```
In [424]: d0,d1 = np.ogrid[:m,:n]

In [425]: val[d0,d1,idx-1]
Out[425]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

Comment: That's great, just wondering, is there also a way to do it with np.choose?

Comment: @nickpick Sorry I haven't used `np.choose` much, so can't help you there. I just prefer doing it the direct way.

Comment: Makes sense. You seem to be a specialist in fancy-indexing. Do you have any literature you can recommend?

Comment: @nickpick Well the docs seem pretty comprehensive. Though in my case, I learnt through practicing, specially with SO questions. Talking specifically about fancy and adv. indexing, the idea is to use range arrays for dims that go through the length of that dim, i.e we have one one index per length along that dim, if that makes any sense. If we are selecting all elems along a dim, use `:`. That's the idea in a nutshell.

Comment: I can approximate your case with `choose`, but the fit is poor.  `choose` is rare in SO numpy questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do with choose

```
In [23]: np.choose([[1,2,0],[1,2,0]], suitcounts[:,:,:3])
Out[23]: 
array([[4, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3]])
```

`choose` prefers that we use a list of arrays, rather than single one.  It's supposed to prevent misuse.  So the problem could be written as:

```
In [24]: np.choose([[1,2,0],[1,2,0]], [suitcounts[0,:,:3], suitcounts[1,:,:3], suitcounts[2,:,:3]])
Out[24]: 
array([[4, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3]])
```

The idea is to select items from the 3 subarrays, based on an index array like:

```
In [25]: np.array([[1,2,0],[1,2,0]])
Out[25]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

The output will match the indexing array in shape.  The choise arrays have match in shape as well, hence my use of `[...,:3]`.

Values for the first column are selected from `suitcounts[1,:,:3]`, for the 2nd column from `suitcounts[2...]` etc.

`choose` is limited to 32 choices; this is limitation imposed by the broadcasting mechanism.

Speaking of broadcasting I could simplify the expression

```
In [26]: np.choose([1,2,0], suitcounts[:,:,:3])
Out[26]: 
array([[4, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 3]])
```

This broadcasts `[1,2,0]` to match the 2x3 shape of the subarrays.

I could get the target order by reordering the columns:

```
In [27]: np.choose([0,1,2], suitcounts[:,:,[2,0,1]])
Out[27]: 
array([[3, 4, 2],
       [3, 3, 1]])
```